# If-then statement with multiple options

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, multiple-columns

I have been working on an IF statement where there are multiple answers but I can't seem to get the formula to work. The If statement is going to look at two columns of data and should pull back the first NUMBER. Sometimes the first column will say "#N/A N/A" in which case the formula should look to the second column and pull that NUMBER. If both columns say "#N/A N/A" then I would like the answer to be "NR".

In another scenario I will have three columns of data. I would like the formula to pick up the first number in the columns no matter what follows. Again, if all three columns say "#N/A N/A" I would like the answer to be "NR".

I will attach two examples of what I am talking about. Here is the formula I have now but I can't seem to get it to work:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B3),"",IF(D3="#N/A N/A",$D3,$D4))
```

Unfortunately, this formula isn't taking into account if D3 is actually a number. It also doesn't account for if both D3 and D4 are "#N/A N/A".

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Here is the example :

[image: Example 1]

Comment: Is cell `B10` a typo? Should that be **4**?

Comment: Yes sorry, B10 should be 4. Was working too fast!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This allows the use of many columns without the need for multiple nested ifs.

It will return the first column that is not `#N/A N/A`:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(3:3,,AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN(D3:E3)/(D3:E3<>"#N/A N/A"),1)),"NR")
```

So to do more columns simple change both the `D3:E3` to the range desired.  The `3:3` should match the row being searched.

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for looking at my question. I am also curious if there is a function I can replace ISNUMBER with so that it will read letters instead of numbers. I have another table that pulls in just letters in which case ISNUMBER will not work. Thanks!

Comment: See edit, I changed to return the first cell that is not `#N/A N/A`

Comment: Hi Scott, your formula is working perfectly so thank you for that. I'm trying to better understand the AGGREGATE function a little better. I see you have 15 as the function_num which is the SMALL function. Does this mean the formula is bringing back the smallest value? Thanks.

Comment: @BrandonM. yes it is bringing back the smallest column number that does not have `#N/A N/A` in the specified range, and passing that number to the INDEX.

Answer (score 1):

You can check each cell (from left to right) and return the first instance of a numerical value using a combination of `IF` & `ISNUMBER`

---

### Checking 2 Columns

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(D3),D3,IF(ISNUMBER(E3),E3,"NR"))
```

---

### Checking 3 Columns

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(D3),D3,IF(ISNUMBER(E3),E3,IF(ISNUMBER(F3),F3,"NR")))
```

Comment: Thanks for looking at my question urdearboy. Is there a function I can substitute in for ISNUMBER so that it will look at letters instead of numbers? Your formula works perfect for this scenario. I will also have instances where my tables are pulling in letters.

Comment: Swap `ISNUMBER` for `ISTEXT`